# Run test cases from Project A in Project B without copy-and-past

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have two projects: project A and project B. I work with maven-intelliJ.

Is it possible to have Project A test cases in Project B up and running without copying?

I have added a project A dependency to project B. As a result, all project A dependencies got extended to project B and they work well. However test cases from project A do not run from project B.

Any advices?

Comment: Are those tests unit tests? What kind of tests do you have there? If the tests are the same it sounds as some code could be refactored out?

Comment: I have functional tests (no unit or integration).

Comment: Which means you have integration tests. Functional tests are usually categorized as integration tests...that sounds much more like refactoring out things cause from the test perspective they are a lot much alike...